# Can't install drush with composer

Tags: drush, composer

When I run...

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

...I get...

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: consolidation/output-formatters[3.1.12, 2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: consolidation/output-formatters[3.1.12, 2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: consolidation/output-formatters[3.1.12, 2.1.3].
    - drush/drush dev-master requires consolidation/output-formatters ^3.1.12 -> satisfiable by consolidation/output-formatters[3.1.12].
    - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].
    - Installation request for consolidation/output-formatters (locked at 2.1.3) -> satisfiable by consolidation/output-formatters[2.1.3].
```

---

My PHP version is 5.6.11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution in my case was to run...

```
composer global update
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

Previously, I had been running `composer update` but needed to run `composer global update`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a Drupal 8 question; The [recommended method of installing Drush](https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) is to now install it as a dependency of your project, not a system application.

```
composer require drush/drush
```

This will of course install Drush 9. If for some reason you need [Drush 8 then other methods](http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/) are available. But really not having to get the sysadmin involved in order to upgrade Drush is a relief.